# Jenkins not running in an AWS ec2 t2 large instance

Tags: debugging, jenkins

I have not used jenkins as a service.However i have initialized jenkins war file using the command 
java -jar jenkins.war
Now if i need to check if jenknins is running in the linux box or not what would be the relevant command ???
Would it be "Sudo service Jenkins status"
PS.The problem statement is that jenkins was running a few weeks back but now when we hit the url the developers are not able to access the url and it times out.
So how would you check if jenkins is running or not ?

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Comment: From jenkins box use `curl localhost:<port_jenkins_is_running_on>` and see the response. Check jenkins logs usually written to `/var/log/jenkins/`